# How make a php script for a REST

Tags: php, api, rest, curl

I have this API in documentation:

```
curl -X GET -H ‘Accept: application/xml’ -H ‘Content-Type: application/xml’ \
  —user mylogin:mypassword https://subdomain.domain.com/entries
```

And I need to do this with php. I know that I have to use CURL.

Anyone have a good idea?

Thanks!

PD.: Sorry but my English is not very good looking.

Comment: Reading the manual is a good idea. http://docs.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can send xml via curl post in PHP

```
$username = 'mylogin';
$password = 'mypassword';

$xml = 'Your xml';

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://subdomain.domain.com/entries');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username.':'.$password);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 300);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/xml'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```